# How to convert image string base64 to byte in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I had a bit function relate to take photo, choose photo from library and then I will show them by string base64 .However, I would like to get byte of them also. Any solution for that ?

Comment: Are you trying to convert image  to `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: Can you point clearly ? I am newbie :( . Thank you in advance !

Comment: Thank mate . Base on your reply, I have solved it already. Many thank for your help.